# What is lens filter size of Kodak Z990?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter, kodak

I have a Kodak z990 Max digital camera and the filter size is not noted on the lens front and not mentioned in the documentation. I figure it is probably in the range of 50-52mm. Can you help? Kodak online help is no help!!

Comment: Kodak does not specify a thread-size but have you considered a ruler? It's generally good to give unambiguous answers!

Comment: In this camera's case, though, having a ruler plus knowing the common filter sizes would give a *wrong* answer.

Answer (score 2):

The lens barrel of Z990 should have a 48.5 mm thread. This is not a standard filter size, but looks like some people have succeeded in [modifying 49mm filters to fit](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3105531#forum-post-39972736) by filing the thread slightly smaller.

Another option is to use a [filter adapter tube](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0084FEFYU), but it seems very likely that the tube will black out corners and edges on shorter focal lengths.

Comment: How about using a 48mm filter and give the threads a once around wrap with plumbers tape and trim off the excess?

Comment: Nice idea, if you can find such a filter - 48mm isn't a common filter size either. Closest commons sizes are 46mm and 49mm. Make sure the tape isn't self-expanding or sticky on the outside, which would get the filter stuck.